# Overriding the functionality of back and home buttons

Tags: android

Can i override the functionality of `back` and `home`buttons(hardware) in `android`?  i mean like clicking on home button should go to`home screen of my app` instead of `home screen of mobile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Home Buttons:**

=> You can't override the behaviour of home button.

**Back Buttons:**

=> In order to capture or override the default back button press in Android the following onKeyDown method can be implemented by the Activity.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

In case of Android 2.0+ a convince method is provided as

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        // implement your override logic here
       return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for back Button Override

```
 public void onBackPressed() {

    // implement your override logic here
   return;
}
```

for home key : create a home app . refer :
[Android Overriding home key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039500/android-overriding-home-key)

Comment: Voted down for wrong method name and quite sloppy content, removed vote after edit. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);             
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```