# How to show a popup window on click of home key in android?

Tags: android

I have to show a popup window on click of home screen button. I have tried using the below code `onkeydown()`, but on click of home key button it's not coming into the loop.

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)

{

  //do something

}
```

Also i tried using `onUserLeaveHint()`, but no use.

If any one knows about this kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The API doesn't let you capture the press of that key. It's a safety key. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208912/how-can-i-detect-user-pressing-home-key-in-my-activity) question for more details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is it possible to do by calling some services?

Comment: I don't think so. Think of it as a way for Android to provide the user a mechanism to always exit the app. If it were possible, your app could render the user's phone unusable, because you could do whatever in the handling of the key event.

Comment: In other words: even if you could, please don't :) That's not the way Android intended to use the home button.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to override the home button, it is required by the system. See this answer by the Android Developer, Romain Guy https://stackoverflow.com/a/5039586/1578771.

Also, in future its better to use onKeyUp() as you'll be able to use other events like long presses etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is it possible to do by calling some services?

Comment: On Android 4.0 and above, you can set it as a launcher, this might help.

    `<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>`