# How can i override Home button for kitkat versions

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Hi I have to override Home button click in my app.I followed below code for overriding Home button it works fine up-to 4.2.2 versions but it doesn't works in kitkat please provide any suggestions.

```
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    exitAppAnimate();
}

private void exitAppAnimate() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (int i=0; i<recentTasks.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 1 && recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().indexOf(getPackageName()) > -1) {
        // home button pressed
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Overriding home key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039500/android-overriding-home-key)

Comment: This is for only launcher activity but my requirement is for all activities this should work.